# Why does PHP error handler run out of order?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to process input from an AJAX form.  I have written an error handler function to make sure the response is always valid JSON, and it's been working fine so far.  But when I add this PDF generator code using TCPDF, it breaks.  It returns two separate dicts like this:

```
{"error":false,"msg":""}{"error":true,"msg":"Error 2 in tcpdf.php line 7791: unlink(\/tmp\/__tcpdf_ccbb9a106b69bdb317365acaf9c33cb8_imgmask_alpha_b21911b6576fec1bf27dd6546bc66baf): No such file or directory"}
```

I can debug the PDF issue myself.  I just don't understand why the error handler function doesn't work.  It looks like the `generatePDF` function returns an empty string, then this is echoed, and then the error handler runs after that even though I added an explicit `die()` statement.

The error here is triggered by `$pdf->writeHTML()` so my expectation is that would invoke the error handler function, and then die without returning from `generatePDF()`.  Here is a simplified example of the code.

```
<?php
// make sure we always return valid JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
set_error_handler('errorHandler');

// initialize array for AJAX response
$res = array('error' => false, 'msg' => '');

require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

$bodyHtml = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../template.html");
$res['msg'] .= generatePDF($bodyHtml);

// return to AJAX
echo json_encode($res);
die();

function generatePDF($bodyHtml) {
  $pdf = new TCPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->writeHTML($bodyHtml, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='');
  return $pdf->Output(__DIR__ . "/output.pdf", "F");
}

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  global $res;
  $res['error'] = true;
  $res['msg'] .= "Error $errno in " . basename($errfile) . " line $errline: $errstr";
  echo json_encode($res);
  die();
}
?>
```

Comment: you're echo'ing out 2 different `$res` instances; since there is an error, `errorHandler` is ran along with your initial `echo json_encode($res);`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer.  The triggering call from line 7791 is `@unlink($file);`.  The PHP manual says:

> If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.

So my solution is to add a test in the error handler:

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  if (error_reporting()) {
    global $res;
    $res['error'] = true;
    $res['msg'] .= "Error $errno in " . basename($errfile) . " line $errline: $errstr";
    echo json_encode($res);
    die();
  }
}
```